# vimdiff disable/enable color coding

Tags: colors, vimdiff

Is there any way to quickly disable/enable color coding in `vimdiff` ? The problem is, I have colored text in `vim` and the text is invisible is the text-color is Red, and the `vimdiff` too tries to put a background color of Red, making it hard to read.

So, I would like to disable the color coding for sometime, for verifying the text and re-enable it later. Any quick, easy way to do this?

Comment: Related:   [Load a different vimdiff color scheme](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019281/load-different-colorscheme-when-using-vimdiff)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can easily deactivate the coloring in `vim`

```
:diffoff!
```

And to turn it on again

```
:windo diffthis
```

Comment: This does not disable/enable color coding. It turns diff mode off and on.

Comment: @Mihai My answer addresses the issue that is raised in te body of the question. The title does not fully reflect this

Answer (score 19):

put this in your .vimrc:

```
if &diff
    syntax off
endif
```

what it does is disable syntax highlighting if you start in diff mode.

Answer (score 16):

Syntax highlighting in `vim` can be turned off/on with `:syntax off` and `:syntax on`.

Answer (score 8):

For me, editing the number of supported colors (see `:help t_Co`) is the solution:

```
set t_Co=0
```

Difference highlighting has problems with colouring (like yellow on white), whether syntax highlighting is enabled or not.

Difference highlighting, which is the point of vimdiff, still works with this option, but simply as inverse video which is readable here.

You can tune with other options mentioned before but this fixes the readability problem.

Answer (score 5):

`TERM=vt100 vimdiff` should invoke vimdiff with a TERM **temporarily** set to vt100. (until the command finishes). This makes it easy to try others : xterm  or  xterm-color  or   xterm-256color , etc.

Answer (score 3):

You could fix the red color problem by adding the following to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
highlight! link DiffText Todo
```

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13370967/200234